# Can I use Gulp 4 to run tasks in a serial fashion?

Tags: gulp

My code currently uses run-sequence to run a series of tasks. From what I was told I can now do this using native Gulp 4. Can someone confirm if this is possible and if so advise how I could do this.

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('make-prod-ex1', function () {
    makeAppHtml('app/**/*ex1', function () {
        runSequence(
          'makeTemplate',
          'clean-css',
          'make-css-files',
          'make-css-bundle',
          'rename-css-bundle',
          'clean-js',
          'make-js-bundle',
          'rename-js-bundle',
          'rename-index',
          function () {
              console.log("Completed");
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know about this. but what I do is define functions for each task and call the same function names in sequence. simply JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gulp 4.0 `gulp.series()` and `gulp.parallel()` completely replace the task dependency mechanism that was used in Gulp 3.x. That means you can't write things like `gulp.task('task1', ['task2'])` anymore.

Instead of telling Gulp which tasks depend on each other and letting Gulp decide the execution order based on the dependency graph, you now have to explicitly define the execution order by composing `gulp.series()` and `gulp.parallel()` calls. Both can accept task names as well as functions and return functions themselves:

```
gulp.task('make-prod-ex1', gulp.series(
    function(done) {
        makeAppHtml('app/**/*ex1', done);
    }, 
    'makeTemplate',
    'clean-css',
    'make-css-files',
    'make-css-bundle',
    'rename-css-bundle',
    'clean-js',
    'make-js-bundle',
    'rename-js-bundle',
    'rename-index',
     function (done) {
        console.log("Completed");
        done();
     }));
```

As usual you have to make sure to signal async termination by either calling a `done` callback or returning streams in your tasks/functions. From personal experience it seems that Gulp 4.0 is a lot more quick to complain about this than Gulp 3.x was.